# Xbox One Won't Power Up

Tags: xbox-one

So my situation is... The Xbox was left off for around 3 weeks only plugged into the wall, but now it won't seem to turn on either by the button or using the controller.

The power brick just has an orange light, I've unplugged it all and left it unplugged for around an hour before trying again. Still won't turn on.

Next, I borrowed a friend's power supply, again all I got was the orange light and the console wouldn't turn on.

I've also tried unplugging everything except for the power, but that still doesn't work.

**The console is no longer under warranty.**

Comment: That's a lot of facts. What's the actual question?

Comment: Check to see if it's hooked up to the tv.

Answer (score 2):

My Xbox One (original, not the Xbox One S, with the external power supply) has done this once, and I reset the internal surge protector by following the Microsoft support page. I'm unsure if this will help you since you've tried a friend's power supply and that didn't help, but this link helped me -

http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/console/console-wont-power-on

To summarize the points from the article's video about the original Xbox One:

1) Unplug your power cord from the console, unplug the external power supply from the wall, and unplug the cable that connects the external power supply to the wall outlet.

2) Wait around 2 minutes, reconnect the cables to the external power supply and reconnect them to your xbox.

Comment: Can you summarise the content in this link? if the page ever goes down or moves you answer will be invalid

Comment: Yeah, I'll get that taken care of. I didn't even think about that. Thanks for the heads up.